# Consecutive words with regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a new label (boolean value, `true/false`) if two words are repeated in a consecutive way:

For example:

```
d = {'test': ['test test ciao a todos']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

the output expected should be `True`:

```
pat = r'\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b'
df['C']=f['test'].str.contains(pat)
```

However, the output is also `True` when I run this:

```
d = {'test': ['test hola ciao a test']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

pat = r'\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b'
df['C'] = df['test'].str.contains(pat)
```

when my expected output should be `False`.

Can you please tell me what is wrong in the regex code? Thanks

Comment: I do not want to remove repeated words, so this question is not a duplicate of the question someone mentioned above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `.*` says that there can be an unlimited number of characters between the two words.

So simply removing the `*` should solve your problem

```
\b(\w+)\b.\b\1\b
```

[try it](https://regex101.com/r/40X1jc/1)